# Guaranteed graph labyrinth solving sequence

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, recursive-algorithms, tiling

> Starting from a vertex of an unknown, finite, strongly connected directed graph, we want to 'get out' (reach the vertex of the labyrinth called 'end'). Each vertex has two exits (edge which goes from vertex in question to an other one), one exit is labeled 'a', the other exit is labeled 'b'.

> We have limitless 'memory' but, we don't recognize when we arrive at the same vertex again, so at each step we can only pick if we go exit a or exit b, or we recognize when we have entered the exit vertex. Show that there is an algorithm to get out of any maze!

> Write the algorithm. If n is its input, then its output is a sequence 'a', 'b' that exits any maze with at most n vertices.

I got this assignment (math student) in a course to do with algorithms. I don't believe the actual code outputting the 'a', 'b' sequence is particularly difficult once the structure of the function is found mathematically.

I've had multiple ideas, it is clear, that were we to find a sequence that would guarantee a visit to all vertices, we would be done, as one of them must be the "end" vertex. This would be easy, if the edges weren't directed, because we would try all possible 1-long sequences by doing a 1-long sequence and tracing our steps back and doing the next, if we didnt reach the end. Then do the same with 2-long sequences, and so on. I think the longest sequnces we would have to try would be $ 2^n $ in length and we would get an incredibly long sequence but it could be shown to work. But this solution relies heavily on the fact that we could always trace our way back to the vertex at which we start and thereby doing something like a BFS. That doesn't work here, as we can't go back on edges we came from (at least not necessarily).

I also stumbled upon *De Bruijn sequences*. A *De Bruijn sequence* for a given alphabet (in this case, 'a' and 'b') and a given length 'n' is a cyclic sequence in which every possible subsequence of length 'n' appears exactly once. I don't see how this would work, but maybe if we collate this sequence 'n+1' times, we would visit all vertices, because we would be guaranteed to have tried all 'walks' from all vertices, but I don't see this rigorously at all.

That is why I come to you, I need some serious guidance, as I have no clue about this at all

(my related question in CS Stack Exchange: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/167241/graph-labyrinth-solving-sequence/167244?noredirect=1#comment346313_167244)

Comment: Why did you choose the tag “tiling”?

Comment: @Aig  I decided to put that tag, because the solution might have something to do with tiling seeing as we learned about tiling in relation to algorithms and languages. If you do not thik it belongs, I'll make sure to remove it

Comment: Btw, remember that you can accept any one of the answers if you feel that it has sufficiently answered your question (though you certainly don't need to). It might also be a good idea to cross-link to the version of this question you asked on cs.stackexchange; this might be helpful to anyone who comes across either of these posts in the future. In any case, nice first question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only finitely many possible labyrinths on $n$ vertices, where the data defining a labyrinth includes all of the edges, the start vertex, and the target vertex. Say there are $M$ labyrinths, and name them $L_1,L_2,\dots,L_M$. Given a labyrinth $L$ and an arbitrary vertex $v$ of $L$, let $\newcommand\sol{\text{sol}}\sol(L,v)$ be a sequence of $a$ and $b$ which, starting from $v$, takes you to the exit of $L$.

Let $w_1=\sol(L_1,v_1)$, where $v_1$ is the start vertex of $L_1$. The first part of the solution path will be $w_1$.

Let $v_2$ be the vertex you end up on after following the path $w_1$ on the labyrinth $L_2$. Then, let $w_2=\sol(L_2,v_2)$. The second portion of the solution path is $w_2$; as long as the true labyrinth is $L_2$, then we will be done after completing $w_1+w_2$.

Let $v_3$ be the vertex you end up on after following the concatenation of paths $w_1+w_2$ on the labyrinth $L_3$. Then, let $w_3=\sol(L_3,v_3)$. The third portion of the solution path is $w_3$.

We continue in this fashion. Assuming that $w_k$ has been defined, we let $v_{k+1}$ be the result of following the path $w_1+w_2+\dots+w_k$ on $L_{k+1}$, and then define $w_{k+1}=\sol(L_{k+1},v_{k+1})$.

Finally, the solution path which works on any labyrinth is $w_1+\dots+w_M$.

Comment: This is a nice, and a lot coherent rephrasing of Christian's answer (+1)

Comment: I appreciate this phrasing of things. It does seem more clear than the way I worded my answer.

Comment: Yes, this is very well written, I presumed this was what Christian was trying to say. Am I right in saying that this strategy is the same as calling the labyrinths of n vertices $L_1, \cdot$ the possible labyrinths with neither being isomorphic to an other, and then doing the same thing as what you described between the triplets of $\left(L_i, s_j, t_k\right)$ where the latter two are the starting and terminal vertices? It's more natural for me to think of these triplets as opposed to differentiating between isomorphic graphs.

Comment: Yes, I assumed this was what Christian was trying to say, it has been clear to me for a while that this is correct, thank you for this clearly written answer. One question, this is the same as calling $L_1, \cdots$ all possible strongly connected directed graphs with $n$ vertices, each having out-degree 2 up to isomorphism (meaning that in this list of graphs no two is isomorphic), and doing what you said, just iterating through $\left(L_i, s_j, t_k\right)$ with the latter two being the start and terminal vertices, right?

Comment: @user555076 Yes, it sounds like your comment is saying the same thing as my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Define an $n$-labyrinth as a strongly connected directed graph on $0\leq m\leq n-2$ vertices labeled $s,e,1,2,...,m$, where each vertex $v$ is the source of two edges labeled $a,b$. ($s$ stands for "start", and $e$ stands for "end")

For any sequence $S$ in $\{a,b\}^*$, any $n$-labyrinth $L$, and any vertex $v$ of $L$ we denote $S_{v,L}$ the path in $L$ starting at $v$ and taking the sequence of edges in $L$ associated with the sequence $S$.

Here, I provide provide an outline for an algorithm that produces a finite sequence $S$ in  $\{a,b\}^*$ such that for any $n$-labyrinth $L$, the path $S_{s,L}$ passes over the end vertex $e$.

---

> First, generate a list of every possible $n$-labyrinth $(L_1,L_2,\ldots,L_k)$. (there are various ways to do this)
>
> Now, let $S$ be the empty string.
>
> For each $i$ in $1,2,...,k$, perform the following procedure:
>
> > Define $v$ as the final vertex in the path $S_{s,L_i}$.
> >
> > Find a sequence $T$ such that $T_{v,L_i}$ is a path from $v$ to $e$. ($T$ exists since $L_i$ is strongly connected and can be found via a standard breadth-first search algorithm)
> >
> > Append the string $T$ to the end of $S$.
>
> Output the string $S$.

---

To see that the final output $S$ satisfies our requirements, note that for any particular $n$-labyrinth $L_i$, at the end of the step $i$ in the for loop, the sequence $S$ is by construction a sequence such that $S_{s,L_i}$ is a path from $s$ to $e$, and since subsequent itterations of the for loop only append characters to $S$, the final output $S$ is such that $S_{s,L_i}$ is guaranteed to pass over the vertex $e$.

Comment: I don't understand what $v$ is in your loop (in the blockquote). Can you add an example of your algorithm for $n=4$?

Comment: @DS I'll see if I can do that at some point later (at least for part of the algorithm, since this algorithm is very slow). In the meantime, do you understand what the notation $S_{1,L_i}$ means here? It's the path in $L_i$ defined by following the edges given by the string $S$. So $v$ is the final vertex of $S_{1,L_i}$. In other words $v$ is the vertex of $L_i$ that you land on if you follow the edge sequence given by the string $S$ on the $n$-labyrinth $L_i$. If $S$ is empty, then the last vertex $v$ of $S_{1,L_i}$ is simply $1$.

Comment: Nevermind, it is clear now.

Comment: See I understand the basic idea, but I don't understand why you dont do a walk to visit all vertices in $L_i$ in each step. By arbitrarily choosing vertex '$2_i$' is it not possible we miss some vertex? So, instead of going to vertex '2' I was thinking we find a walk that visits all vertices. 
To summarize, we create all possibles n-labyrinths, and enumerate them somehow. In step we imagine we are in $G_1$ at an arbitrary vertex $v_1$ and perform a walk that visits all vertices from $v_i$.

Comment: @Christian E. Ramirez If we haven't found the exit, we go on to $G_2$, and choose an arbitrary vertex, $v_2$ whence we execute the sequence of steps that we have previously done, and from wherever we end up, we perform a walk visiting all vertices. Then we move on to the next graph, chose an arbitrary vertex, do the previous steps from there, and so on. Is this correct? Does it seem right? How will I acutally write the code to generate these sequences

Comment: With what I wrote, I think choosing $v_i$ arbitrarily isn't correct, as if it isn't the vertex we were placed at at the beginning, our walk is wrong. For each $G_i$ we have to choose all $v_1,  ..., v_n$ as a supposed starting vertex, and go through them

Comment: @DS Note that the vertex we call the "end" is completely arbitrary; I just chose "2" to make things more simple. The string $S$ produced by this algorithm is guaranteed to pass over any particular/arbitrary vertex of any $n$-labyrinth, regardless of if we call it "2", "13", "end",  or "chicken nugget".

Comment: I don't have a problem with the naming "2", I just don't see why we don't have to iterate through all possible beginning vertices and potetntial end vertices in $G_i$.

Comment: If you want, you can think about labeling the vertices using "start, end, 1, 2, ..., $k$-2" rather than "1, 2, ..., $k$". Is it clear then that the string $S$ must reach the vertex labeled "end"?

Comment: It is not clear to me that in a given graph, why we don't have to go over all possible (start, end) vertex pairs to make sure we reach the end. In $G_i$ we have to go through all $\left(s_i, t_i\right)$ pairs (always adding the already existing part of our sequence to $s_i$ and finding our way to all possible $t_i$)

Comment: For now, let me rewrite things to make them a bit more clear. I'm struggling to find a way to explain this...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152217/discussion-between-christian-e-ramirez-and-user555076).

Comment: @ChristianE.Ramirez Yes, that was the hole in my understanding earlier, but later I understood that your algorithm works because you have all possible labyrinths, so $2$ in some labyrinth is equivalent to 13 in some labyrinth and so on...